# how to get saveToCassandra and use it?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, databricks, datastax-enterprise

I am using spark-sql v2.3.1 for writing data into cassandra v3.11.1.
To write data frame into cassandra table we can use

```
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") 
 .options(Map( "table" -> tname, "keyspace" -> keyspacename ))
 .mode(SaveMode.Append)
 .save();
```

But with the same version how can I use `saveToCassandra()` method
do i need to add any jars , i already added spark-cassandra-connector and cassandra-driver-core. do i need to add any more jars ? i am getting a sparksession as spark and it does not support  `createDateFrame()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveToCassandra` is in the same package, but it [works on RDD](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#saving-a-collection-of-tuples), not on DataFrames. So, if you want to use that command (really should be a good reason), you just need to get RDD from the data frame by saying `df.rdd`, and calling `saveToCassandra` on it.

Answer (score 0):

sc = spark.sparkContext;

on sc we can call saveToCassandra();

Comment: @AlexOtt ,sir can i have your mail id please, I have below issue https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52873337/revisions

Comment: You need to specify via `spark.cassandra.connection.host`

Comment: @AlexOtt  Already i set in setCassandraConf in spark.cassandra.connection.host , spark.cassandra.connection.port , spark.cassandra.connection.user , spark.cassandra.connection.password etc. but it is reflecting on dataframe but not the rdd , what need to be done , is there any good book datastax cassandra and spark  samples and integration?

Comment: Just use official documentation: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc - it contains most of information.